# Проблема с блоками одинаковой высоты

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Проблема заключается в следующем.

Задал код jquery для выравнивания колонок по высоте. В общем, они выравниваются, но не всегда. Бывает, что выравнивание средней колонки заканчавается посредине контента, и весь оставшийся контент уходит за пределы своего блока и даже за пределы футера.

Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

**Обновление**

Немного исправил ситуацию, overflow:auto поставил для контента. Но главной проблемы это не решило, так как вместо того, что текст уходил за границы, теперь появляются полосы прокрутки (это происходин не всегда). Ситуация немного улучшилась, но еще не решена полностью.

**Обновление 2**

zaryad.org.ua проверьте галерею или акции, вроде немного легче, но иногда все же вылазит. Такое ощущение, что яваСкрипт не до конца работает. Это происходит, если загрузка немного подвисает.
В галерее почти постояно левый сайдбар немного опущен за контент и правый сайдбар.

Comment: А вы покажите пример.

Comment: Может, у вас float не обнулен? Для этого общему блоку с колонками поставьте overflow:hidden; или стоит жесткий height.

Comment: Обновил вопрос